# How to find "Ussd" numbers called with LogCat

Tags: android, logcat, ussd

I'm an Auditor of applications. For some security reasons, I want to find out what USSD code called from an application. I have Logcat running with that connected devices. What I should filter in logcat and how to find the numbers called?

Comment: You need tag to get that

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting image describing details about. How to check Logcat.

Hope this will help you

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ali, But I already know how to work with logcat. I want to find out the ussd numbers called with dialer